# Ошибка в легком sql запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `table_1` в которой есть столбцы `id` - уникальный, `ti`,`at`,`timestamp` - varchar
Нужно Вычесть значение timestamp там, где `at = out` из того, где `at=in`.

У меня ошибка #1066 - Повторяющаяся таблица/псевдоним 'table_1' при выполнении этого кода. Где я ошибся в запросе?

```
select
    id,
    ti,
    SUM(CAST(table_out.timestamp AS int) - CAST(timestamp AS int))
from
    table_1

LEFT JOIN (table_1 ON at= 'OUT') as table_out on table_out.ti = ti
where
    at = 'IN'
```

Comment: Неправда. Должно выдаваться сообщение `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) - CAST(timestamp AS int)) from table_1 LEFT JOIN (table_1 ON at= '' at line 4`.

Comment: *Где я ошибся в запросе?* Знаете, проще сказать, где написано правильно. Ибо весь запрос - одна сплошная ошибка. Не придумывайте свой синтаксис, сервер всё равно откажется его понимать.

Comment: Выложите текстовым форматированным кодом CREATE TABLE таблицы, пример данных как INSERT INTO (3-4 пары записей) и форматированный таблицей требуемый результат для таких данных.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, запрос должен быть приблизительно таким:

```sql
SELECT ti, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp))
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (ti)
WHERE t1.at = 'IN'
  AND t2.at = 'OUT'
```